# Return on a quest all these meta_value

Tags: wp-query

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['src'])):
     $business = $_REQUEST['srcbusiness'];
     $type    = $_REQUEST['srctype'];
     $price   = $_REQUEST['srcprice'];
     $city = $_REQUEST['srccity'];
     $district  = $_REQUEST['srcdistrict'];
$query = (array('post_type'=>'post','category_name'=>$business,'meta_value'=>$type,'meta_value'=>$price,'meta_value'=>$city,'meta_value'=>$district));
 endif;
?>
```

Comment: What is your question and what is your exact problem you are having with your code. Please first read [ask] and check out [help] and learn how to ask a good question, then come back and file an [edit] with the relevant info. Thank you :-)

Comment: I'm guessing a little bit about what the question is but have you searched the site, or checked the Codex, for 'WP_Query'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query):

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['src'] ) ) {
    $query = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
        ),
    );

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['srcbusiness'] ) ) {
        $query['category_name'] = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['srcbusiness'] );
    }

    $fields = array(
        'srctype',
        'srcprice',
        'srccity',
        'srcdistrict',
    );

    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ $field ] ) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => $field,
                'value' => wp_unslash( $_REQUEST[ $field ] ),
            );
        }
    }
}
```